# Database.yml configuration options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I would like to know where I can read about valid configuration options for database.yml for ActiveRecord. I know the basic ones like adapter, database, username, password, etc., but I would like to have the full list for each adapter. Where would I find that?

Comment: http://6brand.com/how-to-manage-your-database-yml.html

Comment: @bilash.saha: I don't see how that answers my question.

Comment: Its not the answer of your question.I think you know all valid configuration options for database.yml.

Comment: .. and what about other adapters? Additionally the page you linked to mentions a 'sochost' option that I didn't know. That's my point whenever I read something about database.yml, new options pop out ... so where is the reference for all of them?

Comment: Sorry.There is nothing i found according to your need.Thinking of writting a blog with all options for database.yml.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a [gist of database.yml examples using mysql, postgres, and sqlite3](https://gist.github.com/961978), and the [Rails 3.2 source code for connection adapters](https://github.com/lifo/docrails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters) provides good insight as well.

Looks to me that the following are the most widely used options:

- adapter
- encoding
- database
- pool
- username
- password
- socket
- host
- port
- timeout

The [Rails 3.2 connection_specification.rb](https://github.com/lifo/docrails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb) file looks like it simply merges any options you include, so I'd say what options you include are dependant on the database adapter you choose to use (lines 58-74):

```
def connection_url_to_hash(url) # :nodoc:
  config = URI.parse url
  adapter = config.scheme
  adapter = "postgresql" if adapter == "postgres"
  spec = { :adapter  => adapter,
           :username => config.user,
           :password => config.password,
           :port     => config.port,
           :database => config.path.sub(%r{^/},""),
           :host     => config.host }
  spec.reject!{ |_,value| !value }
  if config.query
    options = Hash[config.query.split("&").map{ |pair| pair.split("=") }].symbolize_keys
    spec.merge!(options)
  end
  spec
end
```

Comment: Links are broken (except for the gist one).